# Background Image not remaining fixed on scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML/CSS and I am designing a basic web-page. I added a Background Image and showing information on it. But, when I scroll the webpage, the image remains fixed on the starting and when I scroll down, it doesn't show any background. I have attached the image below describing my problem.

**This is my page on opening HTML file**
[image: This is my page on opening HTML file]

**And this is my page on scrolling down**
[image: And this is my page on scrolling down]

**This is my code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        CSS | HOME
    </title>
</head>
<style>
    h2
    {
        color: yellow;
        font-family: courier;
    }
    body
    {
        position: absolute;
        top = 0;
        bottom = 0;
        left = 0;
        right = 0;
        background-image:url("tomb_raider_definitive_edition.jpg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }
    .noselect /* Disable Copy Text */
    {
        -moz-user-select:none; /* Mozila FireFox */
        -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer */
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Chrome, Safari, and Opera */
    }

</style>
<body>
<span style="color:red"></span>
<h2 class="noselect; h2">TOMB_RIDER (2013)</h3>
    <pre class="noselect">
        <!-- Some Info here -->
    </pre>
<p class="noselect" style="font-family: verdana;"><strong>TOMB_RIDER</strong></p>
    <a href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f1/TombRaider2013.jpg">
    <img src="TombRaider2013.jpg">
    </a>
    <table border="1px"; style="border-style:solid;" class="noselect">
        <!-- Table code-->
    </table>
    <h2 class="noselect">Requerment !</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is that the background image should remain fixed and only the content should be scrolled.

I also tried `position: relative;` and `position: fixed;`, but none of them is working. I also searched on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) and [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/) before asking it, but I couldn't find solution to my problem.

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: take a look at background-attachment  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment

Comment: @GCyrillus Thank you man! It worked. I knew I was missing something Stupid. Again Thank you very much for the help. Guys like you make this community wonderful...!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp)

```
background-attachment: scroll|fixed|local|initial|inherit;
```

Check this property this will solve your problem..

Here the value `fixed` is used to fix the background with regard to the viewport.

You can edit your code like this-

```
body
{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    top = 0;
    bottom = 0;
    left = 0;
    right = 0;
    background-image:url("tomb_raider_definitive_edition.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Give this a try

```
body
{
    position: absolute;
    top = 0;
    bottom = 0;
    left = 0;
    right = 0;
    background-image:url("tomb_raider_definitive_edition.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using **`background-attachment: fixed;`** as this will attach the background image to the viewport.